# From ruby array to json in bash

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra

In my chef environment I have a variable like this:

```
"repl_set_members": ["tmongo01", "tmongo02", "tmongo03"]
```

I need to create JSON to be sent to a Mongo instance and build the replica set.

I created a bash file from a template with:

```
template "/opt/create_repl_set.sh" do
  source "create_repl_set.sh.erb"
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode "0755"
  variables(
      :repl_set_name => node['mongodb']['shardname'],
      :members => node['mongodb']['repl_set_members']
  )
end
```

And in the bash template I would have something like this:

```
config = "{_id: '<%= @repl_set_name %>', members: [
<% @members.each_with_index do |name,number| %>
{_id: <%= "#{number}" %>, host: '<%= "#{name}" %>:27017'},
<% end %>
] }"

mongo localhost:27091 --eval "JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand({'replSetInitiate' : $config}))"
```

But the resulting JSON includes a last comma which I don't know how to get rid of.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Don't create JSON by hand like that. Use Ruby's built-in JSON class, pass it an  array or a hash, and let it generate the JSON. There's more to the format than you think and the well-tested JSON class knows what to do.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to remove your last comma would be to use bash string manipulation and call your script as follow :

```
mongo localhost:27091 --eval "JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand({'replSetInitiate' : ${config/%,/}))"
```

Note that this will always delte the last comma in your JSON value, so it will only work if your resulting JSON **always** has an extra comma (i.e. even when your JSON is empty)

Comment: This isn't really related.

Comment: @coderanger In a way, it is, it doesn't tackle the way the JSON is generated but it allows OP to convert a bad JSON into a valid one by removing the extra comma

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is an `execute` resource an `.to_json`

```
mongo_cmd = {
  'replSetInitiate' => {
    '_id' => node['mongodb']['shardname'],
    'members' => node['mongodb']['repl_set_members'].each_with_index.map { |name, number|
      {'_id' => number, 'host' => "#{name}:27017"}
    },
  },
}

execute "mongo localhost:27091 --eval 'JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand(#{mongo_cmd.to_json}))'"
```

Comment: @theTinMan you are right. This is why I was asking for a better idea. Unfortunately, I'm not proficient in Ruby. Could you please give an example, point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: I think you meant to reply to the above comment, but I have the example right here for you ...

Comment: I did as you said. it's working. Thank you. In the same time, I wanted to see an example of what The Tin Man said.

Comment: It's the same thing, I just showed you using to_json instead of the JSON module methods.